# keeping a min field value at 1

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a text field for cart quantity. I don't want to let the user have 0 quantity for any items in the cart. If they want zero then they have to delete the item.

I used

```
    $('.cart_item_quantity input').keyup(function(){
    if((this).val()==0) {
    $(this).val()=1;
}
```

For the field, but it doesn't seem to work. So whenever the cart quantity equals zero, I want it replaced with 1. This would also be if the case was that it equaled null as well.

UPDATED

Here is the full working code

```
       $('.cart_item_quantity input').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val()==0) {
    $(this).val(1);
}
var update_obj = $(this);
var quantity = $(this).val(); // item quantity   NEED TO SANITIZE THIS TO ONLY NUMBERS
var array_id = $(this).parent().siblings(".array_id").val(); // item array number
var item_price = parseFloat($(this).parent().siblings(".cart_item_price").find("span").html()); // price of item
var item_total;
var total_price=0;
$.ajax({        
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : 'ajax/update-cart.php',
    data    : 'quantity='+quantity+'&array_id='+array_id,
    success : function(data) {
        item_total = item_price * quantity;
        update_obj.parent().siblings(".cart_item_total").find("span").html(item_total);
        calculate_total_price();
        cart_contents();
        cart_quantity();
    }
});

});
```

But now I am faced with an issue, that if the field value is null, it reverts to 0. How can I get past that?

Answer (score 2):

use  `val(1)` instead of  `$(this).val()=1;` and you have some syntax errors

try this code

```
$('.cart_item_quantity input').keyup(function(){
      if((this).val()==0) 
         $(this).val(1);
});
```

Comment: yes, I realized it needed to be val(1), and was just editing it. But it's still not working for me. Also another issue, is that if they wanted a quantity of e.g. 2, they would first delete 1, then add 2, but if it disallowed null, then it would become 1 again. So I am thinking now, that this should be onblur not keyup. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

- You haven't closed the `keyup(` bracket.
- You're comparing `(this).val()` rather than `$(this).val()`
- You should be setting value with `.val(x)` rather than `.val() = x`; `.val` is a *function* not a property
- For all we know: `.cart_item_quantity input` looks for an input *that is a descendant of* `.cart_item_quantity`. If you meant an input that has the class `cart_item_quantity` you'd write `$('input.cart_item_quantity')`.

Note that comparing with `"" == 0`  in javascript, so if you compare with `0` you will set the value to `'1'` as soon as the text field is left empty. If you compare instead with `'0'`, you're replacing the value only when the user explicitly types a zero into the text field.

Note also that as a user it may be inconvenient to work with a text field that is being manipulated as you type. Consider using validation instead. You may also want to consider the HTML5 `number` type, where you can set this behaviour declaratively:

```
<input type="number" min="1" value="1" />
```

In that way, it will be plainly visible to the user that a number greater than zero is expected. A user *could* manually type something else, and non-HTML5-enabled browsers will just show a regular input field, so a validation is still warranted.

Comment: Your explications are great but using the "min" attribute is not the best way. User can modify (through firebug & stuff) that value (also in jquery they can do this) so the best way is to make a check in server-side, through php or whatever he has there

Comment: Thanks it works now, but I am left with this issue of when deleting the quantity, it reverts to 1 each time, which would be annoying. Do you think this should definitely be done onblur, rather than keyup?

Comment: @stefanz: Yes, there's no need to go through all that hassle, in chrome you can write whatever you want, and in non-html5-browser wouldn't even implement the `min` attribute. Validation is still necessary, which I've pointed out in my answer.

Comment: @Source: I'm not sure what you mean by deleting the quantity, and the keyup/blur discussion. Check the paragraph above where I comment on comparing with `'0'` rather than just `0`, and that might clear some things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).val()=1;
```

supposed to be

```
 $(this).val(1);
```

To get the value --  **.val()**

To set the value --  **.val(value)**

Also you seem to missing the `$` sign in the if statement

```
if( $(this).val()==0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to.

```
    $('.cart_item_quantity input').keyup(function(){
    if((this).val()==0) {
    $(this).val(1); ///here was the problem..
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are checking cart_item_quantity is not null.So do this.This may help.

```
$('.cart_item_quantity input').keyup(function(){
    if((this).val()=="") {
    $(this).val(1);
}
```

Comment: No, I found an issue with this, if someone deletes the current quantity to update it, then it reverts to 1, which would be annoying.

Comment: This is obvious that if any one delete the quantity,it would me empty cart.So ,if you want to make it 1 ,you can hard code it.